# Symfony Enity Type causing exception

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know this is duplicate question , but i am not able to solve the problem 
I am creating application which requires drop down values need to fetched from database .

My database 
   CustomValues Table

```
  Id , myval
```

Mycontroller

```
    $data = array ();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder ( $data )->add ( 'myval', EntityType::class, array (

            'class' => 'AppBundle:CustomValues',
            'choice_label' => 'myval',
            'choice_value' => 'myval',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder ( 'u' )->groupBy ( 'u.myval' )->andWhere ( 'u.customFieldId = 2' ); 

            } 
    ) )->
add ( 'save', SubmitType::class, array (
            'label' => 'Get Result ' 
    ) )->getForm ();
```

problem is after submission of this form i am getting  error 
 if i select any value example 3 
*The choice "3" does not exist or is not unique*

if in place of myval if  i  use id then form get submited without any error .
reason might be myval is not unique , can any help me with this error